# Optimal way to display data with uneven time interval Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

So What I have is data with an uneven time interval. So I need to show the data as in regular time interval Some data points are displaying correctly. but when there is some gap is between the time points, the Highchart's give a very big line gap in the Highchart's data.

maybe it is better to show the data with an example. So here is the dummy dataset that you can see below.

```
var countArray = ["2020-01-02 11:15:21.743", "2020-01-02 11:15:21.749", "2020-01-02 11:15:21.753", "2020-01-02 11:15:21.757",....]

 var numArray = [2,5,3,6,4,6,3,6,3,6,3,7,3,6,3,5,...]
```

Here is the Fiddle that I have tried. 
https://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/fr6zykv0/

Above, When you run the script. the data points show some gaps. after some gaps. I think it's because of the gap in a time interval.

As. I am working with a large no. of data. I need to remove these gaps.

When I am running the same script with the **Highstock chart**. It works fine. but the speed gets slow. that's why I want it to run this in highcharts only

So what I need is that the x-axis to be shown in the 1-second interval so that the big line comes when the distance in `ms` is large gets removed. or anything to remove this `big line gap`.

Comment: not a real solution, but you might consider flattening the data serverside before pushing a large set of data to the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using Highstock source code, you can create a basic chart and turn on the `ordinal` property which is enabled in stock charts by default.

```
xAxis: {
  ordinal: true,
  ...
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rd1fv0kg/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal

Comment: setting `{ordinal : true}` is not working on large set of data. still showing the same gaps.

Comment: Hi @Chempooro, Could you provide some live example?

Comment: I've got it. I was using Highcharts CDN instead of Highstock CDN in my main file, your solution works. thanks for the help.

Comment: one thing that bothers me is that the time intervals are not same in the X-axis

Comment: Hi @Chempooro, Yes, you are right. That is related with `ordinal` property. I can look for another solution if you want.

Comment: Yes please. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: So you can also try with breaks: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h3tum0kv/8/

Comment: I don't think this break function is soln to this problem, as the time interval in X-axis points is still not equal. Suppose we want to have 1 second time interval based on the X-axis values.

Comment: @Chempooro, it is hard to get rid of the irregular tick interval because all of your data has irregular interval. You can try to calculate in tick positions `tickPositioner` function: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.tickPositioner